# Heatmap color legend with svg gradient not working

Tags: d3.js, d3heatmap

Append a defs (for definition) element to your SVG

```
var defs = svg.append("defs");
```

//Append a linearGradient element to the defs and give it a unique id

var linearGradient = defs.append("linearGradient")

```
.attr("id123", "linear-gradient");
```

//Horizontal gradient

linearGradient

```
.attr("x1", "0%")

.attr("y1", "0%")

.attr("x2", "100%")

.attr("y2", "0%");
```

//Build a color scale

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear().range(["#2c7bb6", "#00a6ca","#00ccbc","#90eb9d","#ffff8c",

```
        "#f9d057","#f29e2e","#e76818","#d7191c"]);
```

//Append multiple color stops by using D3's data/enter step

linearGradient.selectAll("stop")

```
.data( colorScale.range() )

.enter().append("stop")

.attr("offset", function(d,i) { return i/(colorScale.range().length-1); })

.attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d; });
```

Comment: .attr("id123", "linear-gradient"); statement seems to be wrong - there is no "id123" attribute.

Comment: It's just a id name which I have used in linearGradient